# Liquibase 3.5.3 is slow

Tags: liquibase

I have the set of Liquibase scripts which recently got migrated from 2.0.1 to 3.5.3.  Scripts which were running in 25 mins in 2.0.1 is taking about 1 hr 55 mins to execute in 3.5.3.  We cannot afford this increase in time.

Any help is highly appreciated?

Thanks
Manohar

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a handle on this, it would be essential to have some profiling information. Ideally, you would run the 2.0.1 and the 3.5.3 code using the YourKit java profiler, collect the performance snapshots they produce, and then submit that to the Liquibase bug system for analysis.

Comment: Hi Steve, sorry for the delay.  we are creating the ear file using maven and run it using Liquibase.  I am relatively new to Liquibase and am more a database guy.  Can you help me with the steps to run the profiler to collect Performance snapshots?

Comment: Download and install YourKit as described on their website. Then when you run your application, you will need to edit the command line used to launch it so that it has extra parameters like this:

-agentpath:/home/steve/YourKit/yjp-2016.02/bin/linux-x86-64/libyjpagent.so=onexit=snapshot,sampling

You will of course need to edit the agentpath to reflect where yourkit is installed on your machine and which OS ad architecture you are using.